# What is "Spain’s dilemma"?

Tags: spain

> ...the United States emerged from World War II not only controlling the North Atlantic but ruling all of the world's oceans. It also occupied Western Europe, shaping the destinies of countries like France, the Netherlands, Belgium, Italy, and indeed Great Britain itself. The United States simultaneously conquered and occupied Japan, almost as an afterthought to the European campaigns.
>
> Thus did the Europeans lose their empire-partly out of exhaustion, partly from being unable to bear the cost of holding it, and partly because the United States simply did not want them to continue to hold it. The empire melted away over twenty years, with only desultory resistance by the Europeans.The geopolitical reality (that could first be seen in **Spain’s dilemma** centuries before) had played itself out to a catastrophic finish.
>
> Source: "The Next 100 Years" by George Friedman

Remark: Centuries before 1945 year

Answer (score 7):

From the context of the quote, it would seem that the "dilemma" refered to relates to Spain's loss of empire. Spain became heavily dependent on trade (especially gold) from their colonies in the Americas. As Great Britain became a greater naval power, the links to Spain's possessions came under threat.

I'd guess that the dilemma they faced was about investment in their navy. Keeping a large navy up-to-date and ready for sea was (and still is) expensive, both in terms of money and manpower. So expanding their navy to protect their trade would eat into the profits from the American trade and so reduce its value to the economy. The alternative was to keep the navy small and cheap but risk the trade and communications (and, therefore, control of the colonies) in times of war.